# Xcode (Multiple strings in one label)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uilabel

I have two separate strings and i want them displayed in the same label. How do i do that with Xcode.

for example

1st string is called answer1
2nd string is called answer2

how do i make my label display both

Comment: I hope I guessed right that you are looking for a solution for iOS. Xcode is just the IDE we use to write our apps. If your question is not about Xcode itself (e.g. where to configure compiler options) you should not choose Xcode as tag. And welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 7):

```
[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1st string is called %@ 2nd string is called %@", answer1, answer2]];
```

answering on your comment:
have a look at the [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) Namely `stringByAppendingString:`

```
NSString* string=@"";
for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
    string = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d ", array[i]]];
}
```

Comment: Thank You. 

Umm...How about if i have an array of integers like

for (n=0,n<4,n++){
int array[] = {1,2,3,4};
int mutiply = array[n]*2;
NSString *answer = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",multiply];
self.label.text = answer;
}

When i try to display the answer in a label, it only displays 8 instead of 2,4,6 and 8. 
How do i correct this?

Thanks again! :)

Comment: and you better define your array before "for".

Comment: and you better assign that string too ;-) fixed.